# 3 by 3 data set how to row vice cell display

Tags: vba, excel, split

I am using VBA in Excel to split my result data from 6 in a cell to 3 in cell by putting the second half in the next cell down.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim TextStrng As String
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim Result() As String
Dim DisplayText As String

i1 = 4
TextStrng = "A,B,C,G,H"
Result = Split(TextStrng, ",", 3)

For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
    DisplayText = Result(i)
    Sheets(1).Cells(i1, 2).Value = DisplayText
    i1 = i1 + 1
Next i
```

Before the code runs the cell will look like:

- `Cell(4,2): A,B,C,D,E,F`

After the code runs I want the cells to look like:

- `Cell(4,2): A,B,C`
- `Cell(5,2): D,E,F`

---

Here is my sheet before splitting:

[image: My sheet before splitting]

And here is my sheet after splitting:

[image: My sheet after splitting]

Comment: Would suggest to edit title in e.g. *"Display split items in groups of three each"* and to change the example string of your original post  to "A,B,C,D,E,F" to correspond with your wanted result display of "A,B,C" and "D,E,F".  :-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Misinterpreted `Limit` argument in `Split` function**

The split function returns only three partial strings as 1-dimensional zero based array, i.e. it concatenates all following occurrencies normally split by a given delimiter to the last token without removing exactly this delimiter any more. So you get

```
0            "A"
1            "B"
2            "C,G,H"
```

I assume you want to group all occurrencies in group of up to three members instead.

So it would be best not to limit the occurrencies at all, but to subgroup within a loop:

```
Sub testSplit()
Const ROWOFFSET& = 4
Dim TextStrng$, DisplayText$
Dim Result As Variant
Dim ws   As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim i&, j&
TextStrng = "A,B,C,G,H"

Result = Split(TextStrng, ",")

    For i = LBound(Result) To UBound(Result) Step 3
        DisplayText = ""
        For j = 0 To 2      ' in group of 3
             If i + j <= UBound(Result) Then
                DisplayText = DisplayText & Result(i + j)
             End If
        Next j
        ' write to cell
          ws.Cells(i \ 3 + ROWOFFSET, 2).Value = DisplayText
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Not working  :error message box  : Subscript out of range
show now not run the code

Comment: this code working fine for me thanks for your support sir